# Imagemagick not installing with MAMP

Tags: php, imagemagick, mamp

So I read [this](http://www.brybot.ca/archives/Getting-Imagemagick-and-more-to-work-with-MAMP-on-OS-X/) article on how to install Imagemagick with MAMP, and did exactly how it said, (`sudo port install Imagemagick`, everything installed okay, then change the envvars file), yet I still get this error when trying to run a script that uses it:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htroots/active/includes/images.php on line 19
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is working for seemingly everyone except me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HI,

This looks like the Imagick extension is not loaded by PHP.

If you create a php script that only contains this :

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Do you get anything *(like an "imagick" section)* mentionning Image magick in the output ?

If not *(that's probably the case, considering the error you're gettin)*, Image Magick extension probably isn't loaded.

Two ideas, now

- Check you php.ini file : it should contain a line like "extension=imagick.ext" (don't know what "ext" is on a mac, sorry)
- did you restart apache to have te new extension take into account ?
- do you have any error in the PHP/Apache error log ? Like something that said imagick has not been loaded and/or why ?

Comment: Yeah that was sort of it, I ended up reading [this](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread194181.html) thread, which fixed the issue for me.

Comment: No ^^ it's kept as simple as possible ; something like not wanting real "conversations" like on a forum, but just quick questions and answer, if I remember correctly.